# How to change the visibility state in react-native GridView component?

Tags: gridview, react-native

I am working on react-native GridView component, i want to change the visibility state on GridView item click.

So i have a list colors grid but when i'll click on individual item at that it should select and show one tick mark.

**Grid Items**

[image]

**Grid Items on Select**

[image]

Code:

```
export default class filter extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
      this.state = {
           gridDataSourceColor: filterColor,
           isVisible: false,
     };
   }
render() {
     return (
        <View>
            <GridView
               items={this.state.gridDataSourceColor}
               itemsPerRow={6}
               renderItem={this.renderColorItem.bind(this)}
            />
        </View>
     );
}

onItemPressed(item){

}

renderColorItem(item){
  return(
    <TouchableHighlight key={item.id} onPress={this.onItemPressed.bind(this, item)}>
        <View 
            key={item.id} 
            style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 45,
                marginLeft: 2,
                marginRight: 2,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 5,
                backgroundColor: item.color}}>

                <Image 
                    style={{
                        width: 25,
                        height:25}} 
                    source={require('../images/check_mark_icon.png')} />
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
 }
}
```

So on above code when i'll do onItemPressed() at that it should change the state and show the tick mark.

Please kindly go through my post and suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `isSelected` in `filterColor`'s Item.

```
onItemPressed(item){
 var tempFilterColor = this.state.gridDataSourceColor;
   for (var i=0; i< tempFilterColor.length; i++)
   {
         if (tempFilterColor[i].id == item.id) {
        tempFilterColor[i].isSelected = true;
        break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
     }
   }
   this.setState({ gridDataSourceColor : tempFilterColor}); 
}

renderColorItem(item){
  return(
    <TouchableHighlight key={item.id} onPress={this.onItemPressed.bind(this, item)}>
        <View 
            key={item.id} 
            style={{
                width: 50,
                height: 45,
                marginLeft: 2,
                marginRight: 2,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 5,
                backgroundColor: item.color}}>

                {this.renderCheckMark(item)}
        </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
 }

 renderCheckMark(item)
 {
    if(item.isSelected) { // image render only if item selected
        return(
        <Image 
                    style={{
                        width: 25,
                        height:25}} 
                    source={require('../images/check_mark_icon.png')} />
        );
    }
 }
```

Comment: hey i am setting isSelected = true like this var tempFilterColor = this.state.gridDataSourceColor;
      this.setState({ gridDataSourceColor : [{isSelected: true}]});

Comment: hey i did it like this but it's not setting the value var tempFilterColor = this.state = {
                    gridDataSourceColor: [{id: item.id, isSelected: true}],
            };
      this.setState({ gridDataSourceColor : tempFilterColor}); 

        var tempFilterColor = item.isSelected;

Comment: you can take temp variable and assign current state to it. then change `isSelected` to particular item in the list. After changing it, just setState with that temp variable.

Comment: For your solution, Main hint is `renderCheckMark` method

Comment: hey thanks again, i got your logic, can you just tell me is this logic is correct this.setState({ gridDataSourceColor : [{id: item.id, isSelected: true}]});

Comment: I am not sure about this way to do setState.
You can change the value like this.

`function changeDesc( value, desc ) {
   for (var i in projects) {
     if (projects[i].value == value) {
        projects[i].desc = desc;
        break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
     }
   }
}`

Comment: `onItemPressed(item){
 var tempFilterColor = this.state.gridDataSourceColor;
   for (var i=0; i< tempFilterColor.length; i++)
   {
   if (tempFilterColor[i].id == item.id) {
        tempFilterColor[i].isSelected = isSelected;
        break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
     }
   }
   this.setState({ gridDataSourceColor : tempFilterColor}); 
}`

Comment: I have edited the code. Please check and if you find the solution, please mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot Namish...I'll try this logic and let you know